# Теги в теле вопроса не кликабельны

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

В предпросмотре редактора метки метки кликабельны:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вопросе, они уже не кликабельны и показываются "как есть":

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меток избыточные кавычки. Если их убрать, все будет хорошо и красиво.

Comment: Ага, но фича то останется :)

Comment: @Nofate, но все равно странно, почему превью не соответствует конечному результату :)

Comment: Могу предположить, что используются два Markdown-рендерера: один для превью на стороне клиента, второй - для финального сохранения на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка - что они кликабельны в режиме предпросмотра. На самом деле этот синтаксис ошибочный и теги `[tag:«tagname»]`, [tag:«tagname»] вообще не должны распознаваться.

Поскольку в [документации по markdown](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) синтаксис с кавычками не описан, считать его фичей нельзя.

Правильный синтаксис - без кавычек, вот так: `[tag:tagname]`, [tagname](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagname)

Comment: Почему вы добавили тэг [tag:статус-так-задумано], ведь разработчиками так явно не было задуманно? :)

Comment: @gil9red давно известно, не планируется к исправлению, не обещали что будет работать. )) http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE/info

Comment: удобный тег )))

Comment: @gil9red мой любимый тег (притом что я тестировщик по профессии и сам не люблю "это не баг, это фича"). ))